# Nginx authentication bypassed easily - wrong?

Tags: php, authentication, nginx

I have nginx basic authentication setup like so:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {    
           ...
           auth_basic "Restricted";
           auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
           ...
    } 
}
```

It works like a charm if you visit something that isn't re-written.

If I visit a .php-file it loads it up like there's no authentication needed. After which the authentication becomes stochastic on the re-written pages as well.

Any idea of what's up with that?

recap: 
visiting **www.mysite.com** and the authentication WORKS!
visiting **www.mysite.com/index.php** and the authentication is bypassed, firing up the site without asking for user/pwd.

Edit:
  Need I add the same auth_basic stuff to the location ~ .php { ... } as well? I thought adding it to the root took care of ALL subsequent structures, no matter the scripting language etc.

Answer (score 3):

Nginx basic authentication works for the location you have placed it in.

Note that ONLY ONE location will be selected by nginx for each request. This means that placing a command inside `location /` block, this command will be executed only for this location (which means that your request is not captured by any other location block). If you want basic authentication to work for every location in your server, just put it inside every location, or even better inside the server blocks like this

```
server {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
  ...
  location / {
       #auth_basic already active, no need to add it again
       ...
  } 
}
```